# Spring Roo - 'JDBC driver not available for 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'

Tags: spring-roo

I am fairly new to Spring Roo and have a problem with establishing a connection to a MSSQL database. I am using Spring Tool Suite and Roo Version 1.3.1. When I try to test the connection to the database (set up with “jpa setup...”) with “database introspect --schema dbo” I get the following error:

```
        Located add-on that may offer this JDBC driver
        1 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.3 compatible
        ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
        01 Y Y 1.2.4.0010 #jdbcdriver driverclass:net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
....
    JDBC driver not available for 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'
```

After that, I tried to install the driver with:

```
roo> addon install id --searchResultId 01
roo> Target resource(s):
-------------------
   Spring Roo - Wrapping - jtds (1.2.4.0010)

Deploying...
done.
```

The driver also seems to be present in the addon list:

```
...
58 Y Y 1.2.4.0010 #jdbcdriver driverclass:net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.
       This bundle wraps the standard Maven artifact: jtds-1.2.4.
```

But when I try to run the database introspect command again, I still get the above message. As recommended here: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/roo/118692-unable-to-find-the-jtds-driver I tried to manually install the file with the command:

```
osgi start -–url “file:\\\C:\Program Files\Spring Tool Suite\jtds-1.2.4.jar”
```

but I get the exception

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: file:\C:Program
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2947)
```

and the behavior stays the same. I also tried the same with Roo version 2, but there the “database introspect” command seems to be unavailable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an OSGi container you must install OSGi bundles only, regular JAR files cannot be installed in an OSGi container.

The Spring Roo Wrapping project helps you in this way by wrapping regular JARS as OSGi bundles.

Take a look to [Spring Roo Wrapping project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo-wrapping) in order to wrap the MySQL JDBC driver.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried to start the "org.springframework.roo.wrapping.jtds-1.2.4.0011.jar" file from here http://repo.spring.io/spring-roo/org/springframework/roo/wrapping/org.springframework.roo.wrapping.jtds/1.2.4.0011/ but still get the same error.

Comment: Ok, I finally solved it by using the HTTP-URL of the jar instead of the file URL.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
addon install id --searchResultId 01
```

Change it to

```
addon install id --searchResultId 58
```

Then it will install the JDBC driver after that you should be able to continue with the

```
database introspect --schema dbo
```